# Android Studio: JSON Parsing

Tags: android, json

I have an JSON File which I want to parse but don't know how to access it correctly.

It doesn't start with an Object bracket "{" and afterwards a Name like e.g. "actors:" "[" .... ]}

where I would easily create an 
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray("actors");

mine looks more like this

```
[
{
"type": "fuel",
"name": "Aral",
"address": "Somestreet 65",
"lat": 49.8848387,
"lon": 8.6520691 },
{
"type": "amenity",
"name": "Centralstation",
"address": "Centralstreet 20",
"lat": 49.8725, 
"lon": 8.628889,
"icon": "somepicture.jpg" },
]
```

I tried something like

```
try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(status == 200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
                //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.length();i++){
                    Locations location = new Locations();
                    JSONObject jRealObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    location.setName(jRealObject.getString("type"));
                    location.setName(jRealObject.getString("name"));
                    location.setName(jRealObject.getString("address"));
                    location.setName(jRealObject.getString("lat"));
                    location.setName(jRealObject.getString("lon"));
                    //location.setImage(jRealObject.getString("icon"));
                    locationList.add(location);
                }
                return true;
            }

        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But there is an error while parsing it I think it has something to do with "JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("");

can you help me out or point in a direction where I could find my error

Comment: Initialize Json array as : JSONArray jasnArray = new JSONArray();

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my GitHub project: [Json Response Renderer Android project](https://github.com/ashwindmk/Android-Assets-Response-Renderer). This might help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(data);
for (int i=0;i<=jarray.length();i++)
    {
       JSONObject obj1=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
       String address=obj1.getString("type");
       String caseno=obj1.getString("name");
       String casetype=obj1.getString("address");
    }
```

Comment: can I still work with my locationList Array so that I don't have to do String address = obj1.getString("type")?

I tried your example but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray (data);
                  for(int i=0; i< jsonArray.length();i++){
                        Locations location = new Locations();
                        JSONObject jRealObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        location.setName(jRealObject.getString("type"));
                        location.setName(jRealObject.getString("name"));
                        location.setName(jRealObject.getString("address"));
                        location.setName(jRealObject.getString("lat"));
                        location.setName(jRealObject.getString("lon"));
                        locationList.add(location);
                    }
```

-if you get a differnt keys use Iterator to get keys like

```
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```